# Inventory Theory

Tags: inventory, rq-inventory-model

I've been doing a bit of inventory theory, and just wanted to know if I could interpret:

"Tim has decided to keep enough safety stock to prevent a shortage before the delivery arrives during 95 percent of the order cycles.” as “Tim wanting to meet demand 95% of the time”?

Comment: What is your probability function in the model? Is it normal?

Comment: @A.Omidi yes, its normal

Comment: Would you mind revising the title of your question to be a bit more descriptive?

Answer (score 2):

I think the two ways of phrasing it are slightly different:

> prevent a shortage before the delivery arrives during 95 percent of the order cycles

means that in the long run, there will be a stockout in 5% of the order cycles, whereas

> meet demand 95% of the time

is a little ambiguous, but to me it suggests you want to meet 95% of the demands, i.e., stock out for 5% of the demands.

The first measure is the **type-1 service level** (or cycle service level), while the second is the **type-2 service level** (or fill rate).

The two are not the same. For example, if you have 1,000,000 demands per order cycle and you stock out on exactly 1 of them per order cycle, then your type-1 SL is 0% (because you have a stockout in *every* cycle) while your type-2 SL is nearly 100% (because you meet virtually every demand from stock).

The formula that @KevinG included is the safety stock required to meet the type-1 service level (which, it seems, is the service level that the original statement was referring to). But I disagree that the two statements in your original question are equivalent.

Comment: I remember reading that Type 2 SL was to know the average number of stockouts? Thanks for this! :)

Comment: It's 1 minus the average number of stockouts, or really 1 minus the average % of stockouts.

Comment: so could we say that for the first statement, we aren't really talking about SL and we're just referring to the probability?

Comment: No, they are both probabilities. They are just two different definitions of service level. Both definitions are probabilities.

Comment: so just confirming, if in the first statement I used type 1 service level measure that would be correct?

Comment: The first statement *is* type 1 SL. The second is type 2, at least as I interpret the statement.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I believe you can interpret it like this. The term service level describes it well:

> Service level is the probability that the amount of inventory on hand during the lead time is sufficient to meet expected demand – that is, the probability that a stockout will not occur.
>   [Service Level](https://www.skuvault.com/blog/safety-stock-formula/)

Assuming we want to be able to meet 99.9% of the demand would require an disproportionately high safety stock which is not economical for any business.

[image: Relationship between safety stock increase and achieved service level]

This exponential relationship comes from the formula

$$SS = Z_\alpha \times \sqrt{L} \times \sigma$$

where $SS$ is the safety stock, $Z_\alpha$ is the inverse of the standard normal distribution for $\alpha$, $L$ is the lead time (in weeks) and $\sigma$ is the cycle service level.